# Why is SVG width 0 if container is display flex?

Tags: svg, flexbox

When I run the following code in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
    svg {
      border:1px solid green;
      width:200px !important;
      height:200px;
    }
    #container {
      position:fixed;
      top:300px;
      left:800px;
      width:1px;
      height:1px;
      overflow:visible;

      display:flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      justify-content:center;
      align-content:center;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <svg class="e3" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

All I get is a 2 pixel vertical line in the browser.  It seems the width of my SVG is 0 (not including the green borders).  When I delete the css rule `display:flex`, then my SVG circle appears.  I tried to force my SVG to have a `width: 200px !important;` but this rule doesn't seem to take effect.

Why is my SVG not respecting the 200px rule when I use `display:flex` on the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your SVG node is not displaying as you expect because it has a default position of `static`. If you change the SVG node to be `absolute` you'll get the desired behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    svg {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid green;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    #container {
      position: fixed;
      /* changed these for ease of viewing */
      top: 30px;
      left: 150px;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      overflow: visible;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <svg class="e3" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```